# generate overlap set with java

Tags: java, algorithm

have N request with start time and end time . I want to find requests that can overlap. For example :request that have overlap for this example {{R1,R2},{R2,R3},{R4,R5,R6},{R4,R6,R7}}

```
R7                  ------
R6                -----
R5            ------
R4          -----------
R3      ---
R2    -----
R1   ---
```

How can I generate the overlap set with Java?

Comment: Removed NetBeans tag as question doesn't appear to be specific to NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

produce a list of interval endpoints, sorted by time.

iterate through the list in order, while keeping a set of intervals which have started but not yet ended.

when you come across a 'start' endpoint, add the interval the endpoint belongs to to the set.
when you come across an 'end' endpoint, output the current set as one of the sets of overlapping intervals, then remove that interval from the 'current' set.

you'll need to add some extra logic for multiple intervals ending at the same time to prevent duplicate outputs, but that shouldn't be too hard.